# ShareKit Crash on Facebook direct sharing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit to share an item to Facebook and Twitter using this code

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:imageToShare title:textToShare];

NSLog(@"Sharing to facebook...");

SHKFacebook *fbSharer = [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showAnotherViewController) name:@"SHKSendDidFinish" object:fbSharer];
```

Everything works like a charm apart from iPhone 5, where the app crashes. This is the crash report generated:

```
Incident Identifier: B061FE97-D1AF-4919-8004-05E0AA3BD3E2
CrashReporter Key:   1544990de75429552f6f5f8eba0171523bd8db4b
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             ADme [2775]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/D243F9B0-0750-4B67-9380-3D1DCDBA5828/ADme.app/ADme
Identifier:          it.xplace.adme
Version:             7 (1.0.7)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-07-22 15:56:42.955 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.6 (11B651)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc65e7e 0x2db91000 + 872062
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37fc26c2 0x37fba000 + 34498
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc65b84 0x2db91000 + 871300
3   ADme                            0x0016f542 -[FBSession reauthorizeWithPermissions:isRead:behavior:defaultAudience:completionHandler:] (FBSession.m:1676)
4   ADme                            0x0016bf2e -[FBSession requestNewPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:completionHandler:] (FBSession.m:433)
5   ADme                            0x001a5734 -[SHKFacebook send] (SHKFacebook.m:410)
6   ADme                            0x001ba624 -[SHKSharer tryToSend] (SHKSharer.m:864)
7   ADme                            0x001b79ca +[SHKSharer shareItem:] (SHKSharer.m:203)
8   ADme                            0x00108b28 -[ASShareNewViewController shareAction:] (ASShareNewViewController.m:110)
9   UIKit                           0x3041ed9e 0x303df000 + 261534
10  UIKit                           0x3041ed3a 0x303df000 + 261434
11  UIKit                           0x3041ed0e 0x303df000 + 261390
12  UIKit                           0x3040a73e 0x303df000 + 177982
13  UIKit                           0x3041e756 0x303df000 + 259926
14  UIKit                           0x3041e420 0x303df000 + 259104
15  UIKit                           0x3041944c 0x303df000 + 238668
16  UIKit                           0x303eed74 0x303df000 + 64884
17  UIKit                           0x303ed564 0x303df000 + 58724
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc30f1a 0x2db91000 + 655130
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc303e2 0x2db91000 + 652258
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc2ebd2 0x2db91000 + 646098
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2db9946c 0x2db91000 + 33900
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2db9924e 0x2db91000 + 33358
23  GraphicsServices                0x328d32e6 0x328cc000 + 29414
24  UIKit                           0x3044e840 0x303df000 + 456768
25  ADme                            0x0010c446 main (main.m:16)
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x384bbab2 0x384ba000 + 6834


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385716e4 0x3855f000 + 75492
1   ADme                            0x0011ccd4 CLSSignalHandler (CLSSignal.m:305)
2   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x385d4720 0x385d1000 + 14112
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d9a4e 0x385d6000 + 14926
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38523028 0x384d9000 + 303144
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3797198a 0x37971000 + 2442
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3798a6e2 0x37971000 + 104162
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37fc2936 0x37fba000 + 35126
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x379881b0 0x37971000 + 94640
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37987d12 0x37971000 + 93458
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37fc280a 0x37fba000 + 34826
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2db994e2 0x2db91000 + 34018
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2db9924e 0x2db91000 + 33358
13  GraphicsServices                0x328d32e6 0x328cc000 + 29414
14  UIKit                           0x3044e840 0x303df000 + 456768
15  ADme                            0x0010c446 main (main.m:16)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x384bbab4 0x384ba000 + 6836

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3855f838 0x3855f000 + 2104
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x384ae0d0 0x384a6000 + 32976
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x384a861e 0x384a6000 + 9758

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38572c7c 0x3855f000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6e06 0x385d6000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6cc0 0x385d6000 + 3264

Thread 3 name:  com.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3855fa84 0x3855f000 + 2692
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3855f87c 0x3855f000 + 2172
2   ADme                            0x001101e6 CLSMachExceptionServer (CLSMachExceptionInterface.c:179)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d8c5a 0x385d6000 + 11354
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d8bca 0x385d6000 + 11210
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6ccc 0x385d6000 + 3276

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38572c7c 0x3855f000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6e06 0x385d6000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6cc0 0x385d6000 + 3264

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x385978a6 0x38597000 + 2214
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2db93be2 0x2db91000 + 11234
2   IOKit                           0x2e9595f0 0x2e944000 + 87536
3   IOKit                           0x2e95b9c0 0x2e944000 + 96704
4   IOKit                           0x2e96526c 0x2e944000 + 135788
5   IOKit                           0x2e97ae78 0x2e944000 + 224888
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x384a70ac 0x384a6000 + 4268
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x384ab8ee 0x384a6000 + 22766
8   IOKit                           0x2e97ae1e 0x2e944000 + 224798
9   IOKit                           0x2e965230 0x2e944000 + 135728
10  IOKit                           0x2e95f35a 0x2e944000 + 111450
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc25b7e 0x2db91000 + 609150
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc30774 0x2db91000 + 653172
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3070e 0x2db91000 + 653070
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc2eeda 0x2db91000 + 646874
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2db9946c 0x2db91000 + 33900
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2dbdd0d6 0x2db91000 + 311510
17  CoreMotion                      0x2e251364 0x2e218000 + 234340
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d8c5a 0x385d6000 + 11354
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d8bca 0x385d6000 + 11210
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6ccc 0x385d6000 + 3276

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3855fad4 0x3855f000 + 2772
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x384acde0 0x384a6000 + 28128
2   MediaToolbox                    0x2f088a0a 0x2f084000 + 18954
3   CoreMedia                       0x2e1c5214 0x2e1a0000 + 152084
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d8c5a 0x385d6000 + 11354
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d8bca 0x385d6000 + 11210
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6ccc 0x385d6000 + 3276

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38572c7c 0x3855f000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6e06 0x385d6000 + 3590
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6cc0 0x385d6000 + 3264

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3855fa84 0x3855f000 + 2692
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3855f87c 0x3855f000 + 2172
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc30554 0x2db91000 + 652628
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc2ec74 0x2db91000 + 646260
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2db9946c 0x2db91000 + 33900
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2db9924e 0x2db91000 + 33358
6   Foundation                      0x2e5d44bc 0x2e57c000 + 361660
7   Foundation                      0x2e649c32 0x2e57c000 + 842802
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d8c5a 0x385d6000 + 11354
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d8bca 0x385d6000 + 11210
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x385d6ccc 0x385d6000 + 3276

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3a397048
    r4: 0x0026bff8    r5: 0x27d063e4      r6: 0x27d06424      r7: 0x27d063c4
    r8: 0x00000003    r9: 0x3a39fe30     r10: 0x00000006     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x27d063a8      lr: 0x0011ccd9      pc: 0x385716e4
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0xfd000 - 0x230fff ADme armv7s  <28b89d0e97d330a181b6080f2689bc3c> /var/mobile/Applications/D243F9B0-0750-4B67-9380-3D1DCDBA5828/ADme.app/ADme
```

I cannot replicate the crash, it doesn't happen on my iphone 5s nor on the simulator

**** EDIT ****
Further investigations help me detect the error. It's not the iphone 5 the problem. I Have the crash on this method

```
-[FBSession reauthorizeWithPermissions:isRead:behavior:defaultAudience:completionHandler:]
```

and it happens with every other Facebook account (except for mine). Of course i remembered to allow Facebook app access to general public.

Comment: While it appears related to iPhone 5, have you explored other possibilities. Specifically, do you know for sure that the `@"SHKSendDidFinish"` notification is send from the main thread? Since you are executing `@selector(showAnotherViewController)`, you are most definitely doing some UI work. Have you tried `- (void)showAnotherViewController{dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}}`

Comment: Do you have the latest ShareKit version? The SHKFacebook sharer has been simplified a lot recently

Comment: I use CocoaPods to manage dependencies and I use the latest version available (2.5.9)